# Getting null values for time_zone and utc_offset

Tags: python, tweepy

[output file of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsXZD.png)
I am getting the values of time_zone and the UTC_offset as null in the output text file.I need a non null and different value for each tweet that is if a tweet is posted by some person in India the UTC_offset and time_zone of that tweet will be different from a tweet posted in USA and i need those non null values.Also i am getting the incorrect format of the tweet.created_at if i use dataframe.to_json conversion but it is not the case if i use dataframe.to_csv conversion.Can somebody please explain?
P.S-Beginner at python and tweepy

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import json
from dateutil.tz import tzoffset

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
consumer_key = 'mine'
consumer_secret = 'mine'
access_token = 'mine'
access_token_secret = 'mine`enter code here`'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


api = tweepy.API(auth)
# Open/Create a file to append data
#csvFile = open('tweet.txt', 'a')
  #Use csv Writer
  #csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile,delimiter=',')
  results=[]

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="Depression" or "Anxiety",lang="en").items(30):
 if (not tweet.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in tweet.text):
 results.append(tweet)


 def tweets_df(results):
     id_list = [tweet.id for tweet in results]
     data_set = pd.DataFrame(id_list, columns=["id"])
     data_set["text"] = [tweet.text for tweet in results]
     data_set["source"] = [tweet.source for tweet in results]
     data_set["screen_name"] = [tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in results]

     #localtime_tz = tzoffset(user.time_zone, user.utc_offset)
     data_set["created_at"] = [tweet.user.created_at for tweet in results]
    # data_set["place"]=[tweet.place for tweet in results]
     data_set["location"] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in results]
     data_set["UTC_Offset"] = [tweet.user.utc_offset for tweet in results]
     data_set["timezone"] = [tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in results]
    # data_set["year"] = [tweet.created_at.year for tweet in results]
    # data_set["month"] = [tweet.created_at.month for tweet in results]
     #data_set["day"] = [tweet.created_at.day for tweet in results]
     #data_set["hour"] = [tweet.created_at.hour for tweet in results]
     return data_set


 data_set = tweets_df(results)
 #data_set.to_csv("/home/rajneeshkaushal/Documents/Pycharm/hived/tweet_data.txt",header=None)
 out = data_set.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '} {')
 with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(out)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this Link partially answers your question: https://twittercommunity.com/t/upcoming-changes-to-the-developer-platform/104603

According to the new new EU privacy laws, Timezone values in Twitter user objects will become private fields after May 23.